# Userview with no return statement

Tags: python, django

I am told that this piece of code works in django.

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User
    # These next two lines tell the view to index lookups by username
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
```

As i am new to Django. There is no render_to_response or any form of HttpResponse value returned from this view method.

Attached is the views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, RedirectView, UpdateView

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from .models import User


class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User
    # These next two lines tell the view to index lookups by username
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'


class UserRedirectView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):
    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail',
                       kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})


class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    fields = ['name', ]

    # we already imported User in the view code above, remember?
    model = User

    # send the user back to their own page after a successful update
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail',
                       kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})

    def get_object(self):
        # Only get the User record for the user making the request
        return User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)


class UserListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = User
    # These next two lines tell the view to index lookups by username
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
```

How does these views return which url to go to with no return statement at all

Comment: It is there, you just haven't overridden it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using generic views (https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/). Your view is child of DetailView. Take a look at the docs and you will sort things out.

Comment: But it overrides the get_context_data method in this example. Sorry i do not understand what it means exactly. I introduce new variables which are not used. The documentation isnt helping me much

Comment: This isn't a Django issue. As Kroustou and Sayse say, your view is a class and inherits from classes that define all of the methods already.

Comment: Yes it defines all the methods. But how does it know what kind of data i would like in my view? Thats what i do not understand why would it work. I took a look at DetailView example and it already shown a get_context_data method. Or am i missing something fundamental

Comment: It knows because you've told it what model to use and where to get the slug. That's all it needs, and the default implementation of get_context_data just calls get_object which uses those arguments to get the relevant item.